# Updates on View Controller Disappear After Segue

Tags: ios, swift

I've been working through a project and have gotten most of the functionality straight, however there's one part that continues to stump me. I am using MVC format, and I have a two view controllers (one profile and one game). When progress is made on the game, the proper changes to game view controller show (i.e. button disappears and UI background color changes colors). However, when I segue to profile view controller using 'back' on navigation bar and return to the game view controller, the game view controller returns to the default without reflecting game progress.

I've tried unwinding segue, making a delegate going from view controller to model responsible for game play, adjusting my game logic, and trying viewdidload and viewwillappear. I'm running out of ideas.

Here are samples of pertinent code:

Game View Controller

```
   
import UIKit
import Firebase



class GameController: UIViewController, BrainDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var dateUsername: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var questionText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var scoreText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerOne: UITextField!
    var userListOne: [String] = []
    @IBOutlet weak var answerTwo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerThree: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerFour: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var enterFour: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var feedbackText: UILabel!
    
    

    
    @IBAction func logoutPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        do {
          try Auth.auth().signOut()
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
          print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
    }
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var questions = [Question]()
    var Brain = Brain()
    var delegate: brainDelegate?
    
    

   //variables for delegate with json data
    var questioner : String?
    var dater : String?
    var a1 : String?
    var a2 : String?
    var a3 : String?
    var a4 : String?
    
    //For game play
    var answer1: String?
    var answer2: String?
    var answer3: String?
    var answer4: String?
    var puzzlesCompleted = "0"
    
    func didUpdateBrain(narratives: [Question]) {
       self.questions = narratives

                
     }
    
    func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    

    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        minketBrain.delegate = self
        answerOne.delegate = self
        answerTwo.delegate = self
        answerThree.delegate = self
        answerFour.delegate = self
        
        if let localData = minketBrain.readLocalJSONFile(forName: K.minketClues) {
            minketBrain.parseJSON(jsonData: localData)

        }
        
        //Transfer data from Profile Controller
        self.questionText.text = questioner
        self.dateUsername.text = dater
        self.answer1 = a1
        self.answer2 = a2
        self.answer3 = a3
        self.answer4 = a4
        
         

    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        view.reloadInputViews()
        answerOne.text = userListOne.last
        
    }
    


    



//MARK: - Button Logic
    @IBAction func enterPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        enterPressedOne()
        allRight()
        
    }
    
//Other buttons replicate the same code above
    
    
    
//MARK: - Correct Answer Logic
    func allRight(){
        if answerOne.backgroundColor == UIColor.green && answerTwo.backgroundColor == UIColor.green && answerThree.backgroundColor == UIColor.green && answerFour.backgroundColor == UIColor.green {
            feedbackText.text = K.congratsText
            puzzlesCompleted = "1"
            if let allAnswer = scoreText.text, let userName = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email{
                db.collection(K.FStore.collectionName).addDocument(data: [K.FStore.userName:userName, K.FStore.clueDate:dateUsername.text!, K.FStore.totalPoints:allAnswer, K.FStore.completionField:puzzlesCompleted]) { (error) in
                    if let e = error{
                        print("There was an error in data collection to Firestore \(e)")
                    }else{
                        print("Successfully saved data")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
  
//MARK: - Update UI-Each Question

    func enterPressedOne(){
        if let item = answerOne.text, item.isEmpty == true { // need to make sure we have something here
               userListOne.append(item) // store it in our data holder
                print(userListOne)
        }
        if answerOne.text == self.answer1!.lowercased(){
            answerOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            enterOne.isHidden = true
            answerOne.isEnabled = false
            
        }else{
            answerOne.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }


    

    
    

    

 
}
```

Unwind segue function in my profile controller

```
   @IBAction func unwindToDestinationViewController (sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
        print("Unwind")
    }
```

Comment: How do you use the updated values when you return to the first view controller?

Comment: I would like to keep the current values so the user interface reflects the last response.  I am not sure how to hold the updated UI text values and background color, so they present when the user returns to game controller akin to saving the game when you leave the view controller by segue or logging out. One thing I thought about was making a user input array and reflecting the last input. I'm not sure what would be the best way to do this.

Comment: What I mean, is what code have you written in the first view controller to refresh when it re-appears?  Have you written code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`?  You could also add code to the unwind function.

Comment: I've tried using `viewWillAppear` and utilizing `view.reloadInputViews()` and creating game play function in the view controller to put inside the viewDidAppear with no luck. When I used the function in `viewWillAppear,' it came out as the result initially since it wasn't just connected to button. I don't have much experience with reloading data other than with tableviews and the view.reloadInputViews().

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to show at least one of the things you have tried?  You need to explicitly set the properties of your UI elements  when the view re-appears.  How do you initially set the properties of the UI elements?

Comment: Sure thing. I edited the question with my most recent attempt using an array for user responses and having the `viewDidAppear` reflect the textfield being equal to the last item in the array,

Comment: That is a significant edit to your question. I still don't understand how you get from this view controller to the profile view controller you mentioned.  How do those two view controllers share data?  There is a now a delegation pattern.  How is the delegate called?  From the profile view controller?  Nothing in the delegate method actually update your UI.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I figured out how to store and present data through google firebase which achieved the goal instead of using a separate delegate method